# How to get highest resolution on an Apple monitor connected to a Windows laptop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

I have an older Apple display that I am trying to get maximum resolution on from my Dell XPS 13. The display is connected to the XPS (which supports very high resolutions as well) via an Apple proprietary box that converts the signal to thunderbolt.

When connected to a MacBook I can get incredibly high resolution, maximizing the display (so I know that it is possible). When I connect my xps, it shows up as a generic monitor and I can't get a decent resolution from it.

I have tried to turn on unsupported resolutions for the display, but I have already selected the highest available in the list.

I could have sworn that I had this working a while back, but for the life of me, I can't remember how I did it.

Comment: How is the monitor connected (VGA, DisplayPort, Thunderbolt)? What are all the types of all the display ports on the computer and the monitor?

Comment: Please use numbers for the resolutions instead of relative terms. Please provide model numbers for products like Apple proprietary box, Apple display etc.

Comment: Thanks for response... The monitor has an apple proprietary connector that goes through an adapter that connects to the laptop via Thunderbolt. The only option on the xps (and MacBook) is Thunderbolt.

Comment: I am not in front of the monitor so I am unable to provide model numbers. As far as resolution goes, I no longer have the MacBook so I can't replicate that connection to determine the maximum resolution. My xps provides 3456x2160 to the built-in display (which is not the maximum resolution of the monitor as I recall).

Comment: Is there a way to get the windows drivers for Apple displays to work on a windows laptop? If so, where would I look for them?

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452660/how-to-get-highest-resolution-on-an-apple-monitor-connected-to-a-windows-laptop

Comment: I closed the other discussion at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/452660/how-to-get-highest-resolution-on-an-apple-monitor-connected-to-a-windows-laptop#autocomment657252 - thanks for pointing out that stackexchange and superuser are in the same network

Comment: The adapter I am using is this one: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08B7FSVTL?ref_=cm_sw_r_apan_dp_3C0R8DCS8JK7TTG7GB42

Comment: I was able to get my hands on a copy of AppleDisplayInstaller64.exe and ran it then rebooted.  I was hoping for a miracle, but alas, none was to come :-(